# how to connect android to mysql?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

Please help me , I am trying to connect my android app to mysql database in localhost through connection in php and json array, but i cant figure out what is the problem , i cant view the data from database.

Here is my files.

**Connection.php**

```php
<?php 

$db_con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'android') or die ("connection error");;

$query = "SELECT * FROM product";

$results = mysqli_query($db_con, $query) or die ("query error");;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){


    $output[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

and this the android java **"MainActivity.java"** :

```java
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView viewItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        viewItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemView);
        // Button btnViewItems = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewItems);

        getData();
    }

    public void getData() {

        String results = "";
        InputStream isr = null;

        // Http post
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://10.0.2.2:8080/android/Connection.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log-tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            viewItem.setText("Cannot connect to database");

        }

        // Converting response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();
            results = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log-tag", "Error Converting string" + e.toString());
            viewItem.setText("Cannot convert string");

        }

        // prase jason data
        try {
            String s = "";
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(results);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jOb = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                s = s + jOb.getString("id") + " || " + jOb.getString("name")
                        + " || " + jOb.getString("cost") + "\n\n";

            }

            viewItem.setText(s);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log-tag", "prasing json data" + e.toString());
            viewItem.setText("cannot prase json data");

        }
    }
}
```

and the out keep saying : **"cannot prase json data"**.

here is the log error :

```
E/log-tag(1904): Error in http connectionandroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
E/log-tag(1904): Error Converting stringjava.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
E/log-tag(1904): prasing json dataorg.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

thanks

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: When posting questions about exceptions you're getting, **always include the full exception details**.  Currently you're catching that exception, logging is, and not telling us what it says, effectively defeating all help the platform is trying to give you.

Comment: Please include the log from logcat as well :)

Comment: sorry my bad this is the exceptions errors :

05-19 23:34:30.525: E/log-tag(1904): Error in http connectionandroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

05-19 23:34:30.525: E/log-tag(1904): Error Converting stringjava.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

05-19 23:34:30.525: E/log-tag(1904): prasing json dataorg.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: please print your json reposnce here..so we can help you//

Comment: i didnt get wat u mean !!! do u mean the log error ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560562/how-to-extract-json-data-and-insert-in-mysql-php

Answer (score 0):

You need to run HTTP requests on different thread instead on main thread. Android API does not allow running HTTP requests on main thread. Try using `Runnable()` to run http request asynchronously on separate thread.

Comment: thanks for reply, but i dont think this the problem as if u refer back to the log errors i just included u ll find it started with HTTP connection. so i guess its in connection to the database

Comment: Yeah i see that. I guess your problem is in trying to run HTTP requests on main thread. Android has changed this scheme. Its not allowd now. As it was not asynchronous. You need to use Runnable() to do your http requests in their own threads instead of hogging main thread.

Comment: thanks for reply, but can you help me with writing this code am not really familier with it .thanks again

Comment: [HTTP request in NonBlocking Mode ](http://www.androidsnippets.com/non-blocking-web-request). Here it demonstrates how to run HTTP request in nonblocking mode i.e asynchrnously. Hope that helps.